# Custom Order Listing Page With WooCommerce

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I have created a plugin which has a separate page for order listing.. in that it looks like the same as WooCommerce's Order Listing page but. i am unable to get the comments of the order so i added my custom post type to `wc_order_types` after that there is no order listed..  its showing a empty table. ?

```
add_filter( 'wc_order_types',array($this,'add_wc_order_types'),10,3);
public function add_wc_order_types($order_types,$type){
    $order_types[] = WC_QD_PT;
    return $order_types;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I Solved The issue just by adding a if condition in my hook's function

`function add_wc_order_types($order_types,$type){
    $order_type = $order_types;
    if('' == $type){ 
        $order_type[] = WC_QD_PT;
    }
    return $order_type;
}`

Answer (score 1):

`apply_filters( 'wc_order_types', $order_types, $for );` is default `wc_filters` which takes 2 parameters you have asked for 3 here `add_filter( 'wc_order_types',array($this,'add_wc_order_types'),10,3);`  and again supplied 2.

visit http://docs.woothemes.com/wc-apidocs/source-function-wc_get_order_types.html#149 It may help you do this.

Comment: thanks. but it dose not work. i get `false` value when i vardump `have_posts()` in WP_List_Table

Comment: then I guess  `wc_order_types` is unable to retrieve the `$order_types` for some reasons, you should try to find out .

Comment: my hooks returns the value. i checked. it

Comment: Have you checked if it needs early or late binding , you may need to change priority ?

Comment: My Custom WP List Table Class Code : http://pastebin.com/ptQvP9st  
And i Call it using the code : http://pastebin.com/BWSQnK8N

Comment: I can try to do it , but currently working on something, if you will get no answer, I will try once I leave my office.