# Display/Hide a specific category in my woocommerce orders list

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

We are a non-profit, and would like to use woocommerce to receive payments online.
We receive 2 different types of payments :

- Donations (we created a product category for that)
- Payments for products/services we provide, like trainings (other product categories for that)

Is there a way to show on two seperate custom pages the order list of donations and the order list of products/services payments ?
It is very different and it makes sense to display them through different pages/links.

For now all payments appear on the same order list :
[my orders list with donations and products currently mixed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zVFJc.png)

Thank you very much for your help,
warm regards,
Cyrille

Comment: Did you check this? https://www.skyverge.com/blog/add-woocommerce-orders-list-column/ Usually, WP lets you at least order this column - perhaps even filter.

Comment: Or you create a totally custom order listing page, like here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32858182/custom-order-listing-page-with-woocommerce

Comment: Hi Jasie, thank you for your feedback, for the first link it is rather for backend,isn't it ? What i try to do is on the front end, in the client order listing. As my coding skills are quite limited i was hoping to start from the regular page and apply a filter to remove a specific category, so that i don't have to recreate it from scratch, but it seems there is not such filter. I found this which some insights, but i fear it is beyond my skills to apply and test it, i would need more details: https://wordpress.org/support/topic/hide-or-remove-some-category-orders-from-order-history-page/ .

Comment: You either have to code (this is what Stack Overflow is for) or to buy a plugin that offers it (there are at least two).

Comment: Yes understand, i may be interested with these plugins as it would be too difficult for me, could you please name these ? I didn't find plugins which were able to to filter the order listing for a category on the front-end

Comment: Maybe this: https://booster.io/features/woocommerce-admin-orders-list/
But I'd recommend you find someone to code this for you (it is really not difficult: add another column and the filter function should work on that, too).

Comment: Hi, allright thank you for the link and for your advice, i think i will look for someone then